# Dispatch backend call once in Angular app

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular5, ngrx

I'm using Angular 5 with NgRX.

I have a component which defines a form to edit user settings. 
When the form loads, I want to set the current value of the settings in the input fields.

Currently I'm dispatching an event to retrieve those settings from the backend whenever the component is loaded.

```
class SettingsComponent implements OnInit {
  settings$ = this.store.select(fromSettings.getSettings);

  constructor(private store: Store<fromSettings.State>) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.store.dispatch(new SettingsActionTypes.RetrieveSettings());
  }
}
```

The effect which picks up this action:

```
@Effect()
findSettings$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(SettingsActionTypes.RetrieveSettings)
    .exhaustMap(() =>
        this.settingsService
            .getSettings() // http call
            .map((settings: Settings) => {
                return new SettingsFound({settings});
            })
            .catch(error => of(new SettingsNotFound()))
    );
```

This works pretty well, except that whenever a user navigates to my SettingsComponent, the backend is called. I want to use this state management in the frontend to its full extent, and as the state in the backend will only change through the frontend, I don't want to retrieve my settings multiple times.

I know I could dispatch the RetrieveSettings action in my Angular App component, but that means that the backend is called regardless that the user needs his/her settings retrieved.

I could also cache the backend call, but I expect this functionality from the state store...

**So how could I execute my backend call when the SettingsComponent is loaded for the first time?**

Comment: I think you can keep user settings in `store` and then just check if it exists in `SettingsComponent`'s constructor. If it doesn't then dispatch the action.

Comment: Add an element 'loaded' to the state?

Comment: Move setting service to login level ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use bygrace's answer made me think about applying the same principle in the initialization of the component.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.settings$
        .do(settings => {
            if (!settings) {
                this.store.dispatch(new SettingsActionTypes.RetrieveSettings());
            }
        })
        .take(1)
        .subscribe()
}
```

Although I still feel there should be a more elegant solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You could have your effect check the ngrx store and ignore the action if the data is already fetched. If you have some kind of expiration on the data then you could check for that rather than just the data existing.

Something like this:

```
@Effect()
findSettings$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(SettingsActionTypes.RetrieveSettings)
    .withLatestFrom(store.select(...)) // select your state
    .filter(([action, state]) => state == null) // if not initialized
    .exhaustMap(([action]) => ...); // initialize state
```

So you would keep dispatching the action wherever you require the state to exist. You could also use a route resolver or something similar to do the dispatch instead of putting it in your component. I like to do that when I have a number of components under the same parent route that require the data or when I need multiple parts of state to exist and don't want to repeat the dispatches in lots of components.

Alternatively you could create a service that has an internal reference to the store and exposes each slice of state as an observable. On access or subscribe it would ensure that the state is hydrated. This is probably a better option than spreading the logic around your app as to how your state is hydrated. I find that if I spread it out then I forget to initialize it sometimes and I get these weird bugs where I may or may not have the required data on a page based on the previous pages I visited.

#### The problem in general

There are a lot of possible approaches to this problem and I personally haven't settled on one. I find that subscribing to state and dispatching an action to hydrate it is similar to giving my dinner order to a waiter and then telling the kitchen what ingredients to go buy at the store. It creates a conceptual tight coupling where I as the consumer have to know how what I am consuming is composed. In an ideal world the mere act of subscribing (giving my order) would tell the producer(s) what they needed to do without further instruction from the consumer/subscriber.

In ngrx the producers seem to be disconnected from the consumer by design. Similar to a message bus. This makes sense in light of supporting multiple actors (api, client, ...) affecting the same slice of state. If you only have one remote actor (api) as a producer then maybe it makes more sense to just cache the data in your api (`shareReplay(1)`).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement and was able to implement it using a service class which held state and Observables.

When my component initiates and calls `getRegions` to load options for a drop down list I have, the first time my component calls `getRegions` the service class will go to the server but the 2nd time the service is called it will not go to the server but instead return the stored value.

***Code***

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
import { of } from "rxjs/observable/of";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { DropdownOption } from "./dropdown-option";

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
  })
};

@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {
  regions: Array<DropdownOption>;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  getRegions(): Observable<Array<DropdownOption>> {
    if (this.regions) {
      return of(this.regions);
    } else {
      return Observable.create(observer => {
        this.httpClient
          .get<Array<DropdownOption>>("config/regions", httpOptions)
          .subscribe(
            data => {
              this.regions = data;
              observer.next(this.regions);
            },
            err => {
              //Handle error
            },
            () => {
              observer.complete();
            }
          );
      });
    }
  }
}
```